# How can I seed objects with relational fields in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

Complete Node.js beginner with strong Django background here, I am building a small platform to listen music online (MEAN stack).

I have a hard time using seeds for testing purposes, here is my attempt so far:

```js
var TrackSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

```js
Track.find({})
    .remove(function () {
        Track.create({
            title: 'Foo',
            user: User.findOne({ email: 'admin@admin.com' })._id
        }, {
            title: 'Bar',
            user: User.findOne({ email: 'test@ŧest.com' })._id
        }, function () {
            console.log('Finished populating tracks');
        });
    });
```

I can't find a way to link a Track to a User. Tracks are correctly served at `api/tracks` but if I uncomment the line where I set a user for the track, `api/tracks` then return an empty list (no error message provided).

Comment: Have you checked what's in your DB for `user` field?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything (findOne doesn't trigger any error, nor result). Like if my seed for users wasn't saving objects until all seeds are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `mongoose` as your database wrapper? If so, it doesn't support synchronous queries.

You will have to return your `User` in a callback function, then have your `Track.create` method inside it.

```
User.findOne({ email: 'admin@admin.com' }, function(error, user) {
    Track
        .create({
            title: 'Foo',
            user: user._id
        });
});
```

Comment: I can understand the logic behind that. However, I got nothing in both `error` and `user`. The seed file for users is correctly required before the one for tracks.